# Is it safe to store OAuth WRAP access tokens in a cookie?

Tags: php, cookies, oauth

I'm planning to setup a website that would access an oauth wrap framework. I was thinking of storing the access token on the client machine as it is. I do NOT want to maintain a database of temporary tokens, etc on the server.

Should I be doing do? Or should I encrypt it? What else do I need to successfully manage a non-database utilizing oauth service?

I'm sorry, but this IS a duplicate of my question - [Save OAuth WRAP access tokens directly on client machine in a cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349274/save-oauth-wrap-access-tokens-directly-on-client-machine-in-a-cookie) - I dont know why I didnt receive any responses to that...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Save OAuth WRAP access tokens directly on client machine in a cookie?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349274/save-oauth-wrap-access-tokens-directly-on-client-machine-in-a-cookie)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41076736/is-storing-an-oauth-token-in-cookies-bad-practise/41079976#41079976