# Is storing an OAuth token in cookies bad practice?

Tags: html, cookies, web-applications, oauth-2.0, oauth

Is storing an OAuth 2 token in cookies bad practice? If so, what are alternatives for a web app?

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40376819/204699) that has a comparison of possible options and their pros and cons for storing security tokens in browser-based client applications.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I definitely wouldn't do it. When security is involved you should not store stuff, in places where others can access it. So don't store it anywhere, especially client-side.

That being said, it's not bad practice, per se if handled properly. See [this](https://auth0.com/blog/ten-things-you-should-know-about-tokens-and-cookies/) comprehensive article about it.

Comment: Storing it under a session cookie seems to be a good way to go. Any objections with this method?

Comment: It all depends on how it's being handled, can somebody else use the token if the users leaves from the computer and does not close the browser? I can't answer that as i don't know what you use it for. There are too many things to be said, all of which are explained in the article or in other resources, better than I ever could and so you have to draw your own conclusions if your approach has any flaws.

Comment: I don't think this answer makes sense. Sessions inescapably require storing something on the client, no way around it. We just have to decide *what* to store and *how* to store it. The question being asked is: are access_tokens an okay thing to store in the session cookie, or should something else be stored?

Comment: @LucianWischik the inescapability you mention is not that inescapable if you configure you app to store your session variables in the db or server-side. In that case you only store session identifiers in a cookie. I think it doesn't make sense to you because you can't know what you don't know. I would suggest reading up on ways to store session stuff. My answer in other words is that i wouldn't store a security token in a cookie client-side if i can avoid it. Maybe unless it's fullproof encrypted, which the question doesn't mention, does it?

Comment: @TigOldBitties You say to store session identifiers in a cookie. That is storing something on the client -- as I said, inescapable. The question is *what* to store and what guarantees must it have? If someone eavesdrops a session identifier what will they get out of it? If someone eavesdrops an access token will they get any more or less out of it? If the answer is "I don't know but my rule of thumb is only ever store session identifiers on the client" then that's not an answer to the question. If the answer is "access token is weaker than sessionID because of XYZ" then that'd be a real answer

Comment: @LucianWischik I believe you are missing what TigOldBitties meant.  He said to store on the SERVER side session (or use db rules) and to avoid the client side cookie storing of sensitive data which as you said, you'll need to make good decisions on what we store there.  I assume as does TigOldBitties that you don't do much backend (server) coding and therefore, would only be thinking in the terms of client side when discussing cookies or sessions.  So, as TigOldBitties said. it IS escapable (client side cookies with sensitive data) when you use a server (backend)

Comment: "You should not store stuff in places where others can access it" is correct. Storing an encrypted token in a session cookie that is httponly and secure is a place where others can't access it. 

Storing them database-side is "safer", I tend to agree but given how often applications in the wild have an SQL injection vulnerabilities, where, once in, they can access ALL sessions I think it's overrated to think that it's safer, it all depends on how you secure things. Both are fine, both need proper safety measures.

Comment: @BrechtDeRooms Exactly.

Answer (score 24):

Whether you can store the access_token in cookies depends on following things:

1. Is the access_token stored in cookie encrypted or not (it definitely should be)
2. Access_token is a bearer token so it is not tied to browser flows. Cookies in general are meant for maintaining state in browsers. So if lifecycle of token is same as cookie, go ahead otherwise not.  When I say lifecycle, I mean lifespan, etc.
3. Also, please consider this fact too that access token is not identity token
4. Access tokens are completely client side, and servers that generally use cookies to maintain sessions, mostly maintain matching server side session as well.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I have a silly question about pt 1, what is the difference between a random string (the access token) from an encrypted random string? In both cases if I can steal the cookie string, encrypted or not, I can impersonate the client. What I'm missing?

Answer (score 5):

Cookies have maxSize of 4kb. So if you are saving a lot of info in the token - you will get an error.

Answer (score 1):

Done correctly, storing access tokens in cookies can give you the best and most reliable browser security.

**STRONGEST BROWSER STORAGE**

Issue cookies with HTTP-only and SameSite=strict settings. Always encrypt them using a strong algorithm such as AES256-GCM.

**ACCESS TOKEN COOKIES**

Issue an access token in a reference format, similar to a UUID. Encrypt it into a secure cookie, which will be small in size and never exceed browser or HTTP server limits.

Issue refresh / ID cookies to separate paths, such as `/refresh` and `/id`, so that these cookies are not sent in API requests. Limiting cookie sending is a good practice.

The access token cookie is an API credential that is only sendable to web entry points into APIs. These are protected by [OWASP CSRF Prevention Best Practices](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html).

One of the advantages of this type of cookie is also that it keeps the backend stateless and easy to manage. In OAuth, the authorization server manages token storage. This prevents the need for apps to build and secure their own backend token stores.

**EXPLOIT WINDOWS**

An HTTP-only cookie is just an HTTP header. If stolen somehow, consider also the exploit lifetime. Using the access token lifetime (eg 15 minutes) as a cookie lifetime reduces the time for exploits compared to some session cookie solutions, which may provide a header that can be replayed for hours.

**CONCURRENT API REQUESTS**

Some session cookie solutions originate from website designs, which used to reload the whole page on every user action. Whereas modern JavaScript apps often instead lay out a tree of views, which may call APIs concurrently:

```
<>
  <View1 />
  <View2 />
  <View3 />
</>
```

For such apps, whatever cookie solution you use, ensure that it copes with concurrent requests and expiry conditions reliably. Solutions such as rewriting cookies on every backend request are therefore not reliable.

If using an access token cookie, when an access token expires, all 3 views will receive a 401 response. The app then needs to perform a synchronized token refresh, to rewrite the access token cookie, then retry all 3 API calls, as in [this code of mine](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final/blob/master/spa/src/plumbing/oauth/authenticatorImpl.ts#L153).

Reliability may be harder to ensure if the access token renewal occurs server side, leading to race conditions where some API requests use token refresh that fails due to sending an old refresh token.

**LOGOUT**

One advantage of session cookies is that it is easier to deny all access on logout. Eg if a user grabbed a cookie HTTP header and replayed it after logout. This feels attractive to some developers, whereas the deeper security requirements are often better met by following OAuth semantics, where an access token cookie replayed in a similar manner may be accepted by APIs for a short time after logout.

**SUMMARY**

Using the latest cookies is an [OAuth best practice](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps). Aim for short API credential lifetimes, a core principle of OAuth. But also select a reliable design based on the style of app you are building.

Answer (score -1):

yea you can only if you are securely storing it. follow this link for more about cookie security.
https://techblog.topdesk.com/security/cookie-security/