# Flask - send JSON data to client before redirecting with make_request

Tags: python, json, flask, response.redirect

I have this callback url that has a redirection:

```
@spotify_auth_bp.route("/callback", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def spotify_callback():

    SPOTIFY_TOKEN_URL = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"

    CLIENT_ID =   os.environ.get('SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID')
    CLIENT_SECRET = os.environ.get('SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET')
    REDIRECT_URI = os.environ.get('SPOTIPY_REDIRECT_URI')

    auth_token = request.args['code']

    code_payload = {
        "grant_type": "authorization_code",
        "code": auth_token,
        "redirect_uri": REDIRECT_URI,
        'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
        'client_secret': CLIENT_SECRET,
    }

    post_request = requests.post(SPOTIFY_TOKEN_URL, data=code_payload)

    # Auth Step 5: Tokens are Returned to Application
    response_data = json.loads(post_request.text)

    access_token = response_data["access_token"]
    refresh_token = response_data["refresh_token"]
    token_type = response_data["token_type"]
    expires_in = response_data["expires_in"]

    token_info = {'access_token': access_token,
                  'refresh_token': refresh_token,
                  'token_type': token_type,
                  'expires_in': expires_in}

    res = make_response(redirect('http://localhost/about', code=302))

    # I'd rather send token_info to `localStorage` at my client, instead of setting cookies
    #res.set_cookie('access_token', access_token)
    #res.set_cookie('refresh_token', refresh_token)
    #res.set_cookie('token_type', token_type)
    #res.set_cookie('expires_in', str(expires_in))

    return res
```

---

Is there a way of sending 'token_info' above with `jsonify()` (or else) to client via `make_response()` before redirection occurs?

Comment: `res = make_response('<script>document.location.href="/about"</script>');...` I guess maybe

Comment: care to give a formal and complete answer? thanks!

Comment: @JoranBeasley your script redirects, how do I pass json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Please read foot-notes if your concern is about the OAuth flow!*

According to [HTTP 302 Redirect - is a message-body needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8059662/2437450), you can return a body in a `302 Redirect`. Indeed [RFC2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.3.3) doesn't forbid to send a response body.

Well, I'm not a Flask expert, but this should do the job. It returns the JSON in the body of the `302 Redirect` response. Pay attention that you should also set the right `Content-Type` header (not done in my example).

```py
import json
from flask import Flask, redirect, Response
app = Flask(__name__)

def jsonResponseFactory(data):
    '''Return a callable in top of Response'''
    def callable(response=None, *args, **kwargs):
        '''Return a response with JSON data from factory context'''
        return Response(json.dumps(data), *args, **kwargs)
    return callable

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    token_info = {
        'access_token': '...',
        'refresh_token': '...',
        'token_type': '...',
        'expires_in': '...' 
    }

    return redirect(
        'http://localhost/about',
        302,
        jsonResponseFactory(token_info)
    )
```

Btw, if your client needs to read the token, *it should not automatically follow* the redirect! Furthermore, I don't know if a `302 Redirect` is the best answer to your OAuth callback endpoint. But all of this depends on the context.

Edit:
Here are some notes after feedback from comments.

1. You should not store tokens in the `localStorage`. There is a good explanation from [Auth0 website](https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/guides/store-tokens#don-t-store-tokens-in-local-storage). Furthermore, browsers (starting with Safari) [will now drop localStorage after 7 days without user interaction](https://webkit.org/blog/10218/full-third-party-cookie-blocking-and-more/)
2. Again from [Auth0](https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/guides/store-tokens#if-a-backend-is-present) (and I fully agree) the token should be handled server-side.
3. I'll let my answer as it is (even if the scope is not ideal) because it's actually answer to your HTTP related question.

Comment: thanks! it should not follow redirect, but send the body BEFORE redirect. I just need body sent so I can store data in `localStorage()`. does it make sense?

Comment: Actually the body is sent before the redirect is done. But if I well understand your use case this is a callback for the "Authorize Code Grant". If so, there are multiple things here:
  - IMO you should not store the access_token or the refresh_token in the localstorage (multiple reasons, a good guide here: https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/guides/store-tokens#don-t-store-tokens-in-local-storage)
  - IMO (again) you should deal with your access/refresh token in your backend (again a good guide here: https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/guides/store-tokens#if-a-backend-is-present)

Comment: I'll edit my answer to give you more details about your comment... ;-)

Comment: I know, and I have an active question with an open bounty regarding my doubts about this handling of tokens. [https://stackoverflow.com/q/60859658/3451339]. some say that keeping states at backend is not desirable, due to scaling afterwards, and staletess practices, and at least my secret credentials are not exposed. go for the answer!

Comment: I edited this one. :-) I'll take a look to the other question ASAP! I hope this one could already help Flask users which needs to response with a body in a `302 Redirect` even if it's not really your "end purpose".